# Using a carousel as a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, date, meteor

I am building a meteor app with a planner containing a list of things to do on a specific day.

On loading the app, the date defaults to the current date. The user should then be able to slide through a carousel to pick different dates, with the details for that day populated into the calendar from a mongoDB.

I want to be able to populate the slides with the correct content +/- 3 days either side of the current date selected. When a user slides left or right, the date should change, and the content in each slide should match +/-3 days.

I am currently using swiper, but I'm not convinced it's going to do what I want it to, as I need to dynamically load on the content, and the slide count doesn't work correctly.

I currently have this:

```
var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
slidesPerView: 7,
spaceBetween: 30,
centeredSlides: true,
initialSlide: 3,
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  clickable: true,
},
onSlideChangeEnd: function () {

  //  Get the active slide from the slider
  let newNumber = mySwiper.activeIndex;

  //  Work out if we've gone forward or backwards and how much by
  let difference = changeStatus.get() - newNumber;

  //  Get the current date, and use the difference to subtract. 
  //  We can subtract a negative to make a positive so this also lets us add
  let currentTaskDate = moment(taskDate.get());
  let newTaskDate = moment(currentTaskDate).subtract(difference, 'days');

  // change current 
  taskDate.set(newTaskDate);
  changeStatus.set(newNumber);

}});
```

This allows me to go through the dates, but doesn't help with loading in content dynamically. I imagine I would need just 7 slides, with the selected slide always being the current date.

I have a function that finds the dates here:

```
tasks() {
// Set variables to query start and end of day
const startDateToQuery = moment(taskDate.get()).startOf('day').toString();  
const endDateToQuery = moment(taskDate.get()).endOf('day').toString();  

// Put an error here so we know if it hasn't returned anything.
let t = Tasks.find({taskDate: { $gte: new Date(startDateToQuery), $lt:new Date(endDateToQuery) }},  { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
if (t.length > 0) {
  return t;
} else {
  return [{ error: 'No Content Found' }]
}}
```